# Unity Editor has "Stack trace could not be displayed" error at launch

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-10, game-development, stack-trace

Unity Editor has "Stack trace could not be displayed" error at launch. I'm using windows 10 my graphic card is Intel.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by loading a different Unity project first.  Then, upon going back to the original project, things worked fine.

If the issue persists, check your 3D settings in your Nvidia Control panel and run Unity.exe on your integrated graphics instead.  After making this change you may need to restart the Unity Hub and you may still need to load a different project first.